# Under what conditions does the Parse HTML event get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a bottleneck in my rendering of an HTML page with multiple backbone views. I used Chrome Dev Tools's Timeline profiler and saw a big amount of Parse HTML events. My question is:

Does this necessarily mean the DOM was touched each time, or is the Parse HTML event also triggered when manipulating HTML in a detached jquery object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about backbone except that it is a framework.

It *can* mean that the **DOM** was touched each time but it does not need necessarily. You will trigger parsing events obviously when you are loading **HTML** document and also when you are playing with one of these  `innerHTML`, `outerHTML`, `innerText` `insertAdjacentHTML`, `DOMParser` interface but these are just tip of the iceberg. A lot of stuff will trigger parse HTML events.

For example:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  parser.parseFromString('<p>lorem</p>','text/html');
},5000);
```

This will trigger **HTML** parser every 5 seconds but it will not touch **DOM**.
But when you use for example `document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Hello</p>'`
you will trigger parsing events as well touch the **DOM**.
So you can have parse events even if you are not directly touching the DOM.

Comment: And how about when creating a jQuery element and manipulating outside the DOM? For example: ```$('<div></div>').append('<span></span>')```

Comment: This will trigger only parse HTML events, but not touch live DOM structure. You just created something that is floating in memory. I am not sure what jQuery use under the cover(maybe document fragment) but dev tools just show HTML parser activity.  But if you decide to add this to live DOM then you will trigger a series of events that browser needs to do to render this onto the screen roughly in this order - evaluate script , parse HTML, recalc style, layout, paint, composite.